# How to show a list of items?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I need to show a list of tweets. each tweet can be highlighted programmatically and also I can add some new controls to the tweet item. and I am using data binding.

for my purpose above, I thought of using a `LongListSelector` but it is too buggy, and it seems that I can't access a collection of its items (can I?). what else is suitable for showing a list of items, each item can contain some other controls, and also supports binding? I don't see another thing in the toolbox? is there any ester egg?

It's windows phone 8 app.

Comment: What is wrong with LongListSelector? And yes you can access its item collection, it was assigned by you in code in the first place.

Comment: I want to access its items on the XAML page. your previous answer solved this problem and I'm working on it. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ListBox

```
<ListBox Name="listboxTimeline" Width="450" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,0,5" >
                        <Button Click="btn1_Click" >
                            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                <Image Name="image" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                        <StackPanel Width="337">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName}"  />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

And then you can data bind to this from your CS page. ( The above code is just a sample)